# Insert XML data in database

Tags: c#, sql, xml

In my code i have converted SVG(XML) file into C# objects after converting it i want to insert the XML data in database but is unable to insert

Below is the code

```
 try
        {
            string uri = @"C:\Users\iqra\Desktop\SVGXMLToJsonApp\SVGXMLToJsonApp\File\3rect.svg";
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Svg));
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(uri))
            {
                Svg result = (Svg)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                //Console.WriteLine(result);
                List<Rect> List2 = new List<Rect>();
                string con = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=FloorPlan;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con))
                {
                    string query = "select * from Stand_Details";
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    SqlDataReader dr;
                    conn.Open();
                    dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Rect newItem = new Rect();
                        newItem.Id = dr["Id"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["Id"].ToString();
                        newItem.X = dr["x"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["x"].ToString();
                        newItem.Y = dr["y"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["y"].ToString();
                        newItem.Class = dr["Class"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["Class"].ToString();
                        newItem.Height = dr["Height"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["Height"].ToString();
                        newItem.Width = dr["Width"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["Width"].ToString();
                        List2.Add(newItem);
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }

                List<Rect> thirdlist = new List<Rect>();
                foreach (var item1 in result)
                {
                    bool isMatch = false;
                    foreach (var item2 in List2)
                    {
                        //if (List1.SequenceEqual(List2))
                        if (item1.Id == item2.Id && item1.X == item2.X && item1.Y == item2.Y && item1.Class == item2.Class && item1.Height == item2.Height && item1.Width == item2.Width)
                        {
                            isMatch = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("Record Exist");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(con);
                                cnn.Open();
                                string update = "SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF;Update Stand_Details set Id=@Id,x=@x,y=@y,Class=@Class,Height=@Height,Width=@Width where Id=@Id";
                                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, cnn))
                                {
                                    //Loop through the and get of parameter values
                                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", item1.Id ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", item1.X ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", item1.Y ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", item1.Class ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", item1.Height ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Width", item1.Width ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    isMatch = true;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isMatch)
                    {
                        thirdlist.Add(item1);
                    }
                }
                foreach (Rect p in thirdlist)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Create SQL conection to your database here
                        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(con))
                        {
                           // Open your connection
                                cnn.Open();
                                //Change the table name here
                                string sql = "SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF;INSERT INTO Stand_Details(Id,Class, Width, Height,x,y) VALUES (@Id,@Class, @Width, @Height,@x,@y)";
                                // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
                                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
                                {
                                    //Loop through the and get of parameter values
                                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", p.Id ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", p.Class ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Width", p.Width ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", p.Height ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", p.X ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", p.Y ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                                    //Execute the query
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = ex.Message.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

Below is my class

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "style", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
public class Style
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "rect", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
public class Rect
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "x")]
    public string X { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "y")]
    public string Y { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "class")]
    public string Class { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "width")]
    public string Width { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "height")]
    public string Height { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "g", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
public class G
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "rect", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public Rect Rect { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "text", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public Text Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "text", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
public class Text
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "transform")]
    public string Transform { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "class")]
    public string Class { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "svg", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
public class Svg
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "style", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public Style Style { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "style")]
    public string _Style { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "g", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public List<G> G { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xlink", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xlink { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "x")]
    public string X { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "y")]
    public string Y { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "viewBox")]
    public string ViewBox { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "space", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
    public string Space { get; set; }
}
```

and below is the XML data that i want to insert in database

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0) -->
<svg version="1.1" id="_x30_" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 1366 768" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1366 768;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.7087;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.st1{fill:#105689;}
.st2{font-family:'ArialMT';}
.st3{font-size:56.5499px;}
.st4{fill:#4554A5;}
.st5{font-size:56.5574px;}
.st6{fill:#2776BB;}
</style>
<g id="LWPOLYLINE">
<rect id="idrect3" x="251.4" y="-0.3" class="st0" width="866" height="300.2"/>
</g>
<g id="LWPOLYLINE_1_">
<rect id="idrect2" x="248.6" y="366.5" class="st0" width="500.3" height="400.2"/>
</g>
<g id="LWPOLYLINE_2_">
<rect id="idrect1" x="811.4" y="364.2" class="st0" width="300.2" height="404.1"/>
</g>
<g id="TEXT">
<text id="idnano" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 515.7997 166.1773)" class="st1 st2 st3">Nano Tech</text>
</g>
<g id="TEXT_1_">
<text id="idmigalo" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 420.2463 553.5321)" class="st4 st2 st5">Migalo</text>
</g>
<g id="TEXT_2_">
<text id="idprime" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 883.9615 567.5667)" class="st6 st2 st5">Prime</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Written code for insert and update but not able to access result variable in loop

foreach (var item1 in result)

giving error as "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Svg' because 'Svg' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator' SVGXMLToJsonApp C:\Users\iqra\Desktop\SVGXMLToJsonApp\SVGXMLToJsonApp\Program.cs 58 Active"

Tried the article u have given but not able to insert it in database because the method is simple.
Let me explain you how i want to insert data in DB
Below is my columns in DB to store data as given below

```
1st Row data:- Rect_Id (idrect3), x(251.4) ,y(-0.3) ,rect_class(st0) ,height(300.2) ,weight(866) ,text(Nano Tech) ,transform(matrix(1 0 0 1 515.7997 166.1773)), Text_Id(idnano), text_class(st1 st2 st3)

2nd Row data:- Rect_Id (idrect2), x(248.6) ,y(366.5) ,rect_class(st0) ,height(400.2) ,weight(500.3) ,text(Migalo) ,transform(matrix(1 0 0 1 420.2463 553.5321)), Text_Id(idmigalo), text_class(st4 st2 st5)

3rd Row data:- Rect_Id (idrect1), x(811.4) ,y(364.2) ,rect_class(st0) ,height(404.1) ,weight(300.2) ,text(Prime) ,transform(matrix(1 0 0 1 883.9615 567.5667)), Text_Id(idprime), text_class(st6 st2 st5)
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: What are you using to save to your database?

Comment: @David I'm testing it now, and it appears to be the last line `List<Svg> obj = dyn`

Comment: use this => `Svg obj = dyn;` instead of `List<Svg> obj = dyn;` because your xml doesn't contains `<svg>` element more than one

Comment: Ok This question is based on :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641923/error-in-deserializing-the-xml-data-in-c-sharp/52736928?noredirect=1#comment92546802_52736928 And you will have to use the code there to convert your xml into objects. So Sana you only have half of the question done here. You need to show the whole thing.

Comment: What does you database table(s) look like?  You probably have to flaten out the your classes to match the database.

Comment: Why do you want to store the SVG in you database as serialized JSON anyways? Why not either store the File Location as a string or store the direct SVG File as such? (This can be done using datatypes such as Blob in your DB)

Comment: your converting a single item to a list i believe this is your problem @ershoaib is right with his suggestion as a second suggestion to have your classes perfectly match id suggest using this [XMLToCSharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) its an easy to use converter that converts your xml to a proper c# class so you can use it without any issues

Comment: This will give you the correct result and then you can easily do with it what you want ill post this as an answer just in case someone else comes across this and needs this info

Comment: @HeadJ.E.M. I have changed the class also but as given in above example of database i only want to fetch some elements to store in Sql DB but i am unable to do it because by using above code all elements are fetched from XML file

Comment: @SanaKhan if your xml is just going to be an svg file as you mentioned then loading the entire file is still file you can then concatenate the file's attributes as required see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Firstly as @Archlight said thats a great reference document and just for anyone else who ever needs this i usally end up using this site for all xml related items

[XML2CS](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) it converts your xml to a easy integrate-able  and usable xml item

which in the OP's case would be perfect for what he needs

here is the example output of the site and here is how you can use it in your app

```
    /* 
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    */
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="style", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public class Style {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="rect", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public class Rect {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="x")]
        public string X { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="y")]
        public string Y { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="class")]
        public string Class { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="width")]
        public string Width { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="height")]
        public string Height { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="g", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public class G {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="rect", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
        public Rect Rect { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="text", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
        public Text Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="text", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public class Text {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="transform")]
        public string Transform { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="class")]
        public string Class { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="svg", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
    public class Svg {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="style", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
        public Style Style { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="style")]
        public string _Style { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="g", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")]
        public List<G> G { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xlink", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xlink { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="x")]
        public string X { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="y")]
        public string Y { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="viewBox")]
        public string ViewBox { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="space", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Space { get; set; }
    }

}
```

You can read the file as you wish from here i added a stream example below

```
public static Svg LoadSVG(Stream SVGFile)
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Svg));
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(SVGFile))
                {
                    Svg result = (Svg)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    return result;
                }
            }
```

From here you can call the attributes as you wish for instance

```
var itemid = svg.Id;
```